# Symfony use case for translation domains

Tags: symfony

I have successfully used in my project translation domains. Unfortunately, it's become a bit confusing. In which use cases should i use translation domains? Or when it makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split your translations into separate files.

Domains are not necessary, but it's a good practice not to put all your translations in one file. If you have a lot of translations it can be very difficult to find something in one file.

You can organize your domain structure as you want. For example you can repeat your site structure and to create a separate translation file for each page.